# Dynamic subtotal in php

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic

In my project I need to make the subtotal of the line (quantite*montant) dynamicali.

For the moment I have there:

[image]

I want the montant total it is auto make 1*110 for example and it is directly displayed.

My code :

```
<div id="contenu">
  <h2>Renseigner ma fiche de frais du mois <?php echo $numMois."-".$numAnnee ?></h2>

  <form method="POST"  action="index.php?uc=gererFrais&action=validerMajFraisForfait">
  <div class="corpsForm">

      <fieldset>
        <legend>Eléments forfaitisés
        </legend>
<table width=100%>
        <tr>
        <td>Libelle</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Montant unitaire</td>
        <td>Montant total</td>
    </tr>
        <?php
            foreach ($lesFraisForfait as $unFrais)
            {
                $idFrais = $unFrais['idfrais'];
                $libelle = $unFrais['libelle'];
                $quantite = $unFrais['quantite'];
                $montant = $unFrais['montant'];                 
        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $libelle ?></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="idFrais" name="lesFrais[<?php echo $idFrais?>]" size="10" min="0" autocomplete="off" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $quantite?>"  onkeyup="calculer()">
        <td><input type="text" id="montant" value="<?php echo $montant ?>" disabled></td>
    </tr>           
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </table>           
      </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="piedForm">
  <p>
    <input id="ok" type="submit" value="Valider" size="20" />
    <input id="annuler" type="reset" value="Effacer" size="20" />
  </p> 
  </div>        
  </form>
```

Comment: U can do it By Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I added another Answer for you.

So basically in your FOREACH Loop you have to create INCREMENTAL VARIABLE

```
<?php
            $incr = 1;
            foreach ($lesFraisForfait as $unFrais)
            {
                $idFrais = $unFrais['idfrais'];
                $libelle = $unFrais['libelle'];
                $quantite = $unFrais['quantite'];
                $montant = $unFrais['montant'];

        ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $libelle ?></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="<?php echo 'idFrais'.$incr; ?>"  size="10" min="0" autocomplete="off" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $quantite?>"  onkeyup="calculer(this)">
        <td><input type="text" id="<?php echo 'montant'.$incr; ?>" value="<?php echo $montant ?>" disabled></td>
<td id='subtotal<?php echo $incr;?>'><?php echo $quantite*$montant; ?></td>
    </tr>

        <?php
              $incr ++;
            }
        ?>
```

Since you already have ONKEYUP='calculer' on your javascript code this below.

```
function calculer( e ){

 var i = e.getAttribute('id').length;
 var input_identifier = e.getAttribute('id').substring(i-1,i);
 var subtotal = document.getElementById('subtotal'+input_identifier)
 var quantity = e.value;
 var montant = document.getElementById('montant'+input_identifier);

 subtotal.textContent = parseInt(quantity) + parseInt(montant.value);

 return;

}
```

This should work.

Comment: No :( when I change quantite the montant total est pas changé directement : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/38/1474370109-screenshot-20160920131435.png

Comment: I have try this : function Calcule()
{
var c1=document.getElementById('idFrais').value;
var c2=document.getElementById('montant').value;
var tt=c1*c2
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = tt;
}

Comment: And :    <td><input type="number" id="idFrais" name="lesFrais[<?php echo $idFrais?>]" size="10" min="0" autocomplete="off" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $quantite?>"  onkeyup="Calcule()">
   <td><input type="text" id="montant" value="<?php echo $montant ?>" disabled onkeyup="Calcule()"></td>
   <td><div id="total"></div></td>

Comment: But it calulate just the first line

Comment: You have to change the type="number" to type="text"
Then you have to make sure that onkeyup="calculer( this )" has "this" parameter and FOLLOW the PHP Script Above I have showed

Comment: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/38/1474379296-screenshot-20160920154759.png

Comment: It's good whith all except the line 0.62 and the name of variable has change my controleur don't working

Comment: You can use ( parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(montant.value) ).toFixed(2)

Comment: And put the name="lesFrais[<?php echo $idFrais?>]" back

Comment: Don't forget to put a check on the Answer.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

please add td for total :

```
  <tr>
            <td><?php echo $libelle ?></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="idFrais" name="lesFrais[<?php echo $idFrais?>]" size="10" min="0" autocomplete="off" maxlength="5" value="<?php echo $quantite?>"  onkeyup="calculer()">
            <td><input type="text" id="montant" value="<?php echo $montant ?>" disabled></td>


    <td><input type="text"  value="<?php echo ($montant*$quantite) ?>" disabled></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: I said, but I want where I make nombre 2 the montant total change directly, no when I send the formulaire

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add the following 4th TD.

```
<td><?php echo $quantite*$montant; ?></td>
```

That should work.

Comment: I know very well that that so works, but it is necessary to throw the form, except her, I want that the result be posted as soon as the person changed the quantity.

Comment: Well you cannot do that in PHP... you should be doing that using JAVASCRIPT. Your Post says "Dynamic subtotal in php"

Comment: If you want it to be Dynamic with "user Interaction".. you have to do it with Javascript not PHP.

To do so you have to create a Listener in Javascript with document.getElementById('idFrais').addEventListener('keypress',function(){});

Comment: Also, you have to create an incremental variable in your PHP foreach loop and assign it to your input-attribute-id like id="<?php echo 'idFrais'.$incremental_var ?>"

The output should be .. all  inputs in each row should have id='idFrais1'  id="montant1" and so on..

then you can call it in your Javascript .

Comment: I have added another Answer for you check it out.